# How to use the optimizer in tensorflow2 correctly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow2

Im asking myself does the following code do only one step of gradient descent or does it do the whole gradient descent algorithm?

```
opt = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=self.learning_rate)   
opt = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=self.learning_rate)   
train = opt.minimize(self.loss, var_list=[self.W1, self.b1, self.W2, self.b2, self.W3, self.b3])
```

You need to do a number of steps in gradient descent which you determine. But Im not sure if `opt.minimize(self.loss, var_list=[self.W1, self.b1, self.W2, self.b2, self.W3, self.b3])` is doing all steps instead of doing one step of gradient descent. Why do I think it does all steps? Because my loss is zero after that.

Answer (score 0):

`tf.keras.optimizers.Optimizer.minimize()` calculates the gradients and applies them. Hence, it's a single step.

In the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/optimizers/Optimizer#minimize) of this function you can read:

> This method simply computes gradient using tf.GradientTape and calls
> apply_gradients(). If you want to process the gradient before applying
> then call tf.GradientTape and apply_gradients() explicitly instead of
> using this function.

Which can also be seen from the [implementation of minimize()](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/v2.7.0/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py#L499-L532):

```
  def minimize(self, loss, var_list, grad_loss=None, name=None, tape=None):
    """Minimize `loss` by updating `var_list`.
    This method simply computes gradient using `tf.GradientTape` and calls
    `apply_gradients()`. If you want to process the gradient before applying
    then call `tf.GradientTape` and `apply_gradients()` explicitly instead
    of using this function.
    Args:
      loss: `Tensor` or callable. If a callable, `loss` should take no arguments
        and return the value to minimize. If a `Tensor`, the `tape` argument
        must be passed.
      var_list: list or tuple of `Variable` objects to update to minimize
        `loss`, or a callable returning the list or tuple of `Variable` objects.
        Use callable when the variable list would otherwise be incomplete before
        `minimize` since the variables are created at the first time `loss` is
        called.
      grad_loss: (Optional). A `Tensor` holding the gradient computed for
        `loss`.
      name: (Optional) str. Name for the returned operation.
      tape: (Optional) `tf.GradientTape`. If `loss` is provided as a `Tensor`,
        the tape that computed the `loss` must be provided.
    Returns:
      An `Operation` that updates the variables in `var_list`. The `iterations`
      will be automatically increased by 1.
    Raises:
      ValueError: If some of the variables are not `Variable` objects.
    """
    grads_and_vars = self._compute_gradients(
        loss, var_list=var_list, grad_loss=grad_loss, tape=tape)
    return self.apply_gradients(grads_and_vars, name=name)
```